# convert item in list to int

Tags: list, python-3.x, int

From the code below, I get: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

```
x = list(input("Input a list of integers, seperated by a comma:"))
def histogram(x):
    for y in x:
        print("*"*x)
histogram(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want something that will look a little like:

```
>>> histogram('1,5,1,3')
*
*****
*
***
```

You have to change a few things then.

First is, `x = list(input())` will give you a list of letters/characters in your input. So `list('1,2,3')` will yield `['1', ',', '2', ',', '3']` and I'm sure you dont want to deal with the commas.

Instead, you should use `string.split(',')` to split on every occurence of comma. depending on how you want to do this, you can do it inside your function (like I did below) or directly to the output so that the function expects a list of strings of numbers.

I say "a list of strings of numbers" because `input` returns a string, so even if you enter numbers, it will give you STRINGS. you have to make sure to explicitly cast as `int` to be able to multiply `'*'` by it.

And last, the actual answer to your question? You are calling `print("*"*x)`. I think you meant `print("*"*y)` or more precisely, `print("*"*int(y))`.

Below is what I assume to be working code, but again, I don't know what your expected output actually is.

```
>>> x = input("Please enter comma separated list of numbers: ")
Please enter comma separated list of numbers: 
>>> x = input("Please enter comma separated list of numbers: ")
Please enter comma separated list of numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2
>>> def histogram(x):
    for y in x.split(','):
        print("*"*int(y))


>>> histogram(x)
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*
**
```